# sorting array using nsset key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data, nsset

In my project, i am having array of some custom objects.Each object will be in the following format.

```
 {
enrollementStatus = 0;
enrollementType = 1;
titles =     (
    "0x7b316eb0 <x-coredata://6F003DDD-D6CD-4514-B565-FEF9203F188C/CourseText/p246>"
);}
```

In this object titles is nsset type.while print this object,It will look like

```
   ( "<CourseText: 0x7b316f60>
     (entity: CourseText; id: 0x7b316eb0 data: 
    {\n    course = \"0x7aa69870 <x-coredata://6F003DDD-D6CD-4514-B565-FEF9203F188C/Course/p11>\";\n  
  descr = \"(null)\";\n   
     lang = \"en-US\";\n  
      title = CSDFFFFF;\n})"
```

I want to sort this array based on thistitles(NSSet object) title(alphabetical order).Please give me a suggestion

Comment: but its a type of nsset object.That object only contains "title"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the NSSet and create a sorted NSArray using NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedObjects = [titles sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[titleSortDescriptor]];
```

**Edit 1**
Updated answer as per comments :

As per my understanding your object structure is something like this:

1. Array of *YourCustomObject*, where *YourCustomObject* contains a
   `NSSet` called *titles*.
2. *titles* contain an object of class *CourseText*
3. *CourseText* has a property *title*
4. You want to Sort Array of *YourCustomObject* based on the *title* property of *CourseText*.

For this you can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method of `NSArray`.

```
//arrayOfCustomObjects is the array that contains your objects to be sorted
//Replace YourCustomObject with the actual class of the objects
NSArray* sortedArray = [arrayOfCustomObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(YourCustomObject* obj1, YourCustomObject* obj2) {

    NSString* title1 = ((CourseText*)obj1.titles.anyObject).title;
    NSString* title2 = ((CourseText*)obj2.titles.anyObject).title;

    return [str1 compare:str2];

}];
```

Comment: here what is [titles...] what i have to given?

Comment: titles is the `NSSet` that contains the objects you want to sort. You can replace this with the actual set name.

Comment: please give me a code example..I couldnt understand

Comment: if array contains 5 objects means,How can I get all 5 objects "titles set"?